# Git: Is it possible to make branch use specific version of submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Git pipeline is failing due to missing commit in one of submodules. It is not possible to recover that commit because it was lost during hardware crash. How can we make a branch use older version (commit) of submodule, even after we have the newer version in commit history?

Comment: Where and how is the submodule linked to the ci ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the submodule is a real submodule registered in `.gitmodules` then you should do this in a local worktree:

```
cd <superproject>
git checkout <abranch>
cd <submodule_path>
git checkout <old_commit>
cd <superproject>
git add <submodule_path>
git commit -m "Update submodule"
git push
```